# Radiobutton values are not passing to Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, radio-button

In my View I am using following radio buttons

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="type" asp-for="loremType" value="1"  type="radio" /><label for="rdbLetters">Letters</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="type" asp-for="loremType" value="2" type="radio" /><label for="rdbWords">Words</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="type" asp-for="loremType" value="3" checked="checked" type="radio" /><label for="rdbParagraphs">Paragraphs</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

loremType is the parameter from the Model Class. Even though the value set as 1,2,3 these values are not passed to the controller.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the type of the `loremType`?

Comment: It may help to reproduce the error if you could  show more details of your models and controller related